# Reuse variables from feature file (javascript, wdio, cucumber)

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cucumber

I have a test setup written in javascript, using cucumber and webdriverio.

I define my test scenario in my feature files: 
***example1.feature*** and ***example2.feature***

Mx example1.feature file looks like this:

```
Feature: Submit search term
  As a user who is logged in
  I want to submit a search term
  Because I want to see the search results

Background:
  I am logged in
  And I am on the search view

Scenario outline:
  When I enter and submit the search term <someString>
  Then I can see the results of <someString>

Examples:
  |someString|
  |bananas|
```

This works perfectly, my variables get picked up by example1.page.js and by example1.steps.js

Now I want to reuse this Scenario Outline from example1.feature (including the variable someString) in my example2.feature (and also for example3.feature, example4.feature, ...)

My example2.feature looks like this:

```
Feature: Navigate to details page 
  As a user who is logged in
  I want to submit a search term
  Because I want to see the details of my search term

Background:
  I am logged in
  And I am on the search view

Scenario outline:
  When I enter and submit the search term <someString>
  Then I can see the results of <someString>
  When I click on the details
  Then I get redirected to the details page

Examples:
  |someString|
  |bananas|
```

I try to reuse the parts from example1.page.js, but this breaks my test. Neither example1 runs any more nor does example2. When I remove example2, example1 works. I tried removing and renaming (someString and bananas); it does not work.

The two ways I came up with for solving this problem is to copy over the whole parts from
   example1 to example2 (including locators and the parts from page.js)
   or to include example2 in example1 (making example1 bigger).

However, since I want to reuse this code part also in example3 and
   example4 and so on, I am neither really happy with copying everything
   over nor with making one giant test case...

Can anybody think of a solution to solve this in a nicer way?

Answer (score 0):

The feature files don't seem to be formatted correctly, which may solve the problem. There was a missing `Given` in the first step of the Background (converting it to a description of the Background), and `outline` should be uppercase: `Scenario Outline:`

Hopefully this fixes your issues:

example1.feature:

```
Feature: Submit search term
  As a user who is logged in
  I want to submit a search term
  Because I want to see the search results

Background:
  Given I am logged in
  And I am on the search view

Scenario Outline:
  When I enter and submit the search term <someString>
  Then I can see the results of <someString>

Examples:
  |someString|
  |bananas   |
```

example2.feature

```
Feature: Navigate to details page 
  As a user who is logged in
  I want to submit a search term
  Because I want to see the details of my search term

Background:
  Given I am logged in
  And I am on the search view

Scenario Outline:
  When I enter and submit the search term <someString>
  Then I can see the results of <someString>
  When I click on the details
  Then I get redirected to the details page

Examples:
  |someString|
  |bananas   |
```

Comment: This was a typo from my side, in the original feature file the missing "Given" is included. The problems occurs also within my "validlogin.feature" and "invalidlogin.feature". Bothe tests work fine when I run them seperatly, but as soon as I include both tests in one run they both fail.